# spring security reactive "Invalid credentials" error using Cloud Foundry UAA

Tags: authorization, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, cloudfoundry-uaa

I want to authenticate users with Cloud Foundry UAA provider in my reactive spring boot application.

Following [to this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/cloud-foundry-uaa) I can get token using Tomcat, when my app is not reactive. But I'm getting error with Netty, using starter-webflux. Configuration and screenshots are below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Authorization App
  profiles:
    active: dev
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          uaa:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/userinfo
        registration:
          uaa:
            client-id: webappclient
            client-secret: webappclientsecret
            scope: resource.read,resource.write,openid,profile
            provider: uaa
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/uaa
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
```

After successful login, authorization and setting up scope through UAA my redirect page, where token should be, looks like:

[Invalid Credentials error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlt63.png)

And I can't find any error description or logs

[Web console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwe5h.png)

What could be issue?

Comment: Server debug logs?

Comment: There's nothing in uaa or application logs. Like everything is fine.

Comment: can you please post your full debug logs, so i can take a look.

Comment: Did you find the fix?

Comment: @SAtahAhmedKhan unfortunatly, no. Try to use Keyckloak instead